# Using a variable to eliminate all rows very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a case where a section of a report needs to be turned off or on via parameter.
I have an initial query along the lines of

```
declare @param1 int = 5
declare @param2 int = 10
declare @param3 int = 35
select * from myInlineTVF(@param1, @param2, @param3)
```

... and it runs in about 15 seconds.

When I attempt to add a parameter to allow the rows to be eliminated:

```
declare @param1 int = 5
declare @param2 int = 10
declare @param3 int = 35
declare @INCL_ROWS int = 1
select * from myInlineTVF(@param1, @param2, @param3) where @INCL_ROWS = 1
```

...then it never finishes, at least as long as I've been willing to wait for it (over 10 minutes).

In the final environment those parameters will be supplied from outside by the application (which I don't have control over).  For testing, I'm just running these inside Management Studio.

Is there a better way to do this in a query?  What am I missing?  And, perhaps most importantly, why does this happen?

Comment: At least for your example, have two versions using `if..else` or whatever conditional logic is needed based on the parameter values.

Comment: `@INCL_ROWS = 1` is a constant i.e. unrelated to the results returned - are you sure thats what you intended?

Comment: `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` also often works wonders for such "if only we could interpolate the value of this parameter into the query as a constant" scenarios.

Comment: @Stu Ha, this seems too obvious, but yes, I guess what I'll end up doing.  I'd still like to understand why it hits performance so hard, though?

Comment: @JeroenMostert A good idea, and I did try this, but unfortunately it didn't seem to help

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans for each case, i'm assuming the real situation is less trivial than the example?

Comment: Actually, this is one of those rare cases, where a multi-statement TVF might perform better, because it runs as a separate context, rather than all combined into one statement.

Comment: @Stu yes, definitely less trivial; unfortunately, it never returns with an execution plan for the second case, although I haven't tried leaving it running for longer than about 10 mins

Comment: If you really need a "switch" then the `if else` would be the way to go, the `else` could simply select an empty result set if needed. Have you also tried adding it as an additional parameter and moving the switch criteria into the function?

Comment: Try making it show an *estimated* execution plan if you can't wait for the full execution; these are generally good enough to spot major differences, even if the row counts aren't correct at all. If the estimate doesn't return either, it's a case of the engine missing statistics that it's going to go ahead and sample; in that case waiting is really the only option if you don't want to rewrite the whole thing up front.

Comment: @Stu I ended up just wrapping the main query in an if/else as you suggested.  I tried moving the criteria into the function, but it suffered from the same issue.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yup, I tried the estimated plan, but it never returned.